# Returning nil from init

Tags: cocoa

From the Mac OS X Application Programming Guide, "[Initializing a New Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/DocumentBasedDesign/DocumentBasedDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH5-SW11)" (emphasis added):

> **If you override `init`, make sure that your override never returns `nil`.**
>   Returning `nil` could cause a crash (in some versions of AppKit) or
>   present a less than useful error message. If, for example, you want to
>   prevent the creation or opening of documents under circumstances
>   unique to your application, override a specific `NSDocumentController`
>   method instead.

From Xcode's auto-generated MyDocument.m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
        // If an error occurs here, send a [self release] message and return nil.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Why does Apple give conflicting advice here?

Comment: You may want to file a bug about the conflict. https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idiom is that `-init` may release self and return nil if an error occurs. The document you're citing for "never return nil" is specifically talking about subclassing `NSDocument`. Basically, returning nil is fine in the general case, but it's a bad idea for `NSDocument` specifically. The template file for MyDocument.m doesn't know about the NSDocument case, it's just giving you the general-purpose template for the `-init` method.

Comment: So let's say I'm creating a Core Data-based application, and inside the `init` method of `MyDocument` I'm creating the managed object model. What should `init` do if the MOM can't be created successfully?

Comment: If you can't create your MOM, you should NSAssert(). The program is not going to go forward at that point.